# LED button doesn't work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gpio, led

I have tried connecting a LED with a button like this (from "Adventures in RPi"), but with the far end of the button plugged at G (instead of F).
[image: breadboard]

And I ran it with the following Python program (by following instructions from the said book):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(24):
        GPIO.output(23, True)
    else:
        GPIO.output(23, False)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

But when I tried running the program it didn't work. To debugg it I changed the if code block to this:

```
    print("button")
    ##GPIO.output(23, True)
```

And it resulted in many prints of "button"...

- How can I fix the program (or wiring?) so that the button will turn the LED on?

Thx in advance! :)

**EDIT:**
Here are photos of the actual wiring:
[image: photo of wiring 1]

[image: photo of wiring 1]

Comment: Did you check that the resistor is weak enough to let ~20mA flow through the LED? I know, it's obvious, but still. Also, are you running the program as root / with sudo? You need to.

Comment: @krork I previously made a LED blinker program that worked, with the same resistor, and yes, I ran it as root and with sudo.

Comment: maybe running `GPIO.cleanup()` at the end of the program could help some way for the next run, cleaning buffers or whatnot? Also, you could test whether your Pin 23 is working by the using the shell to turn it on; as root: 

`echo "23" > /sys/class/gpio/export`
`echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction`
`echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value`
`echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value`

Comment: @krork 1. I tried restarted the Pi, so is the GPIO.cleanup() necessary? 2. This might be a bit of a noob question, but how will I know if Pin23 works by running that code?

Comment: I also updated the original question with photos of the actual wiring.

Comment: For the code: "Everything in Unix is a file", even GPIO pins and mouses and keyboards are represented by files on the filesystems.  If you enter those commands in a terminal you communicate with the pins directly via those files. Those commands switch the voltage on the Pin 23 on (`echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value `) or off (`echo "0" > ..`). 
I don't know whether the `GPIO.cleanup()` is strictly necessary, but it has helped me in the past.
I can't see anything wrong with your setup, your problem is bugging me a bit, too.
Edit: Breadboards break, too. Tried a different row for the LED?

Comment: @krork Oh, thx. About the breadboard breaking, I don't think this is the case, I just opened it recently, but I will check another row next time I set up the RPi and update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you have the button around the wrong way. Rotate it 90 degrees and see if that works. It's a very easy mistake to make :)[image]

If that doesn't help, try double checking all your wiring and making sure you have the wires connected to the right GPIO pins

Comment: I am going to try it now, but if that was the problem, than why did the program printed the string from the if-code block?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't fix the problem :( thx for trying anyway. I updated the original post with photos of the actual wiring if you want to check them out.

Answer (score 0):

You write that putting `print("button")` inside the `if` statement *"resulted in many prints of "button"..."* but you don't mention whether it *only* printed when the button was pressed, printed constantly or printed seemingly at random. That's the important part.

Regarding the hardware/wiring...

- try turning the LED around in case you've connected it in reverse. The longest leg/lead is positive.
- The resistor values look like 330 ohm and 10k ohm - that's fine. 330 ohm at 3v3 will allow 10 mAs to flow through the LED which should be enough to turn it on. 10 K is a good pull-up value for buttons in general.
- For good measure, replace the green breadboard wire with a low-value resistor (e.g. 330 ohm). That'll keep the Pi safe from over-currents.

On to the script...

There's no reason to constantly poll the button for changes when the `RPI.GPIO` module supports threaded callbacks. If you use that approach instead, your script will be free to do other things *while* you're listening for button presses. If the script below prints "Button was pressed!" when you press the button, you know that the button circuit and software is working. You could also skip the button circuit and simply connect the GPIO to 3v3 through a resistor to check it directly - much simpler. Anyway, here's a script that'll free up your main loop:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

led_on = False:

def callback_func(pin):
    # you don't really need to use globals here but for now it'll work
    global led_on
    print("Button was pressed!")
    if led_on:
        GPIO.output(23, LOW)
    else:
        GPIO.output(23, HIGH)
    # toggle LED at every button press 
    led_on = not led_on


# change GPIO.RISING to GPIO.FALIING if your button is active low. 
# added 200 ms. of debounce time because you're using a mechanical switch
GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=200)

def main():
    while True:
        print("Main loop isn't blocked!")
        time.sleep(5)
```